# If Statement Gives Blank Results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I can't get the following IF statement to produce the desires results. Result comes up blank.

=IF(B3="168375","500","")

Cell A3 = 168375 so am i missing something that is preventing this statement from resulting in 500 being displayed in cell B3 instead of a blank cell.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your problem is comparing numbers and texts. If A3 contains a number (168375), you cannot use quotation marks. Quotation marks are for texts.

Your formula should be in B3:

```
=IF(A3=168375,500,"")
```

Comment: @McNafa - If your formula `=IF(B3="168375","500","")` was in cell B3, then you should also have seen a warning about circular references. A circular reference occurs when a cell refers to itself, either directly or through a chain of references involving other cells. The warning is shown in the status bar of Excel (under the worksheet tabs and to left).